# Род аббревиатуры

Tags: род, аббревиатура

В связи с ростом правонарушений на дорогах ГИБДД провела месячник безопасности движения.    Вопрос у меня такой , какого рода ГИБДД? И есть ли ошибка в данном предложении?   Главное слово в аббревиатуре Инспекция, значит ошибки нет, в сборнике Цыбулько это предложение выделено  с ошибкой в нарушении связи между подлежащим и сказуемым. Может аббревиатура превратилась в самостоятельное слово как и вуз? Подтверждения этому нигде не нашла. Грамота.ру говорит о женском роде.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ответы: 62497

Answer (score 2):

Ищите главное слово в расшифровке аббревиатуры и определяйте его род: **Государственная инспекция по безопасности дорожного движения**. Главное слово - существительное женского рода **инспекция**.

Значит, ГИБДД тоже женского рода.

Comment: Значит никаких изменений по поводу ГИБДД не было? У составителей сборника  ошибка ?Подготовка к ЕГЭ , 2019, страница 77.

Comment: Посмотрела всё. В 9 нет такого рода ошибки. И в других предложениях, кроме 7, нет. Предложение №7 подходит, конечно, но 7 ещё и ошибку в употреблении существительного с предлогом содержит. Так что ошибка, скорей всего, у составителей сборника.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, одна голова хорошо, а две лучше))))А то учишь одному, а на практике вон как получается )

Comment: Юля, я нашла-таки причину ошибки!) У меня сборник Цыбулько 2017 года.На той же странице, тот же 8 вариант, но типы ошибок АБВГД идут в другом порядке. Предложения о ГИБДД нет совсем, другие предложения совпадают, заменены 1, 5 и 9! А ответы такие же, как у Вас: 62497. То есть ответы просто списаны со старого сборника без учёта изменений в самом задании.

Comment: Вот что значит погоня за деньгами , а детям как быть? Очень все это печально (

Comment: Коллега)))но в таких вопиющих случаях я теряюсь, сомневаюсь, ведь такие издания, по моему мнению, должны очень тщательно проверяться, жаль, что я ошиблась и в этот раз в своей наивной уверенности.Спасибо, что развеяли мои сомнения.)